# Changing assets outputPath doesn't update in html

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to change the `outputPaths` for my assets from the default `assets` to `media` so I can more easily integrate it with my php framework.

In my `ember-cli-build.js` file, I've made the following modifications to my app as defined [here](https://ember-cli.com/asset-compilation#configuring-output-paths):

```
var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    fingerprint : {
        replaceExtensions : [ 'html', 'php', 'css', 'js' ]
    },
    outputPaths: {
      app: {
        css: {
          'app': '/media/application-name.css'
        },
        js: '/media/application-name.js'
      },
      vendor: {
        css: '/media/vendor.css',
        js: '/media/vendor.js'
      }
    },
    'ember-power-select': {
      theme: 'bootstrap'
    }
  });
```

While the generated `application-name.css`, `application-name.js`, `vendor.css` and `vendor.js` files are saved on the hard drive in the correct `assets` directory, the `index.html` file is not updated to match. Instead, it links to the same default `assets/application-name.*s[s]` files.

Any ideas why this isn't working? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fingerprinting to work, the path and file names in your `index.html` file and in your `config.js` file have to match. For example, if you have the below in your config file:

```
outputPaths: {
  app: {
    css: {
      'app': '/media/my-application.css'
    },
    js: '/media/my-application.js'
  },
  vendor: {
    css: '/media/vendor.css',
    js: '/media/vendor.js'
  }
}
```

You'll need to edit your index.html file to match:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="media/my-application.css">
<script src="media/my-application.js"></script>
```